# Why does this keep returning error "Object not found" from Heroku/Parse in swift?

Tags: swift, debugging, heroku, parse-server

I am trying to delete the row where username = usernameSelected from the Heroku/Parse server. Username selected is not nil and does exist on the server. Nothing seem wrong at all, only the "Object not found" instead of deleting the whole row.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Requests")

query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameSelected)
query.limit = 1
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) in
    if error != nil {
    }else {
        if let objects = objects {
            for obj in objects {
                obj.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) in
                    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                    if error != nil {
                       self.alertDisplay("Error", message: error?.userInfo["error"] as! String)
                    }else {
                        self.alertDisplay("", message: "Styles Submitted..! Please wait for your next Style")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Which block is getting that error? The findObjects... or the deleteInBackground...? If the second, are you getting it for all of the objects you delete?

Comment: Just a thought: how have you set the ACLs on this class/object?

Comment: +Lou Franco: the deleteInBackground block, it returns an error (Object not found) while the object does exist.

Comment: +toddg: whats ACLs?

Comment: ACLs are Access Control Lists. Every object has one. They work in conjunction with CLPs (Class Level Permissions) to see who can do what to objects. First, a user's permissions must pass the CLP, if they pass the CLP it checks the object's ACL. You can restrict who can find an object (query without knowing the objectId), get an object (fetch / query with the objectId), create new objects, modify an object (save / destroy).  It's possible that since you can find an object, you have read permissions but not write permissions on this object. Try using the master key.

Comment: Since we also can't see where this is getting called from, it's possible you're actually calling this function twice, so it fetches the list twice, and the first time it goes through it's trying to delete the objects, then the second time the objects are already deleted. Since you're defining the query in the scope, that's possible. You can't call findObjects twice on the same query, it would throw an error, but since you're declaring a new query they could both run and find the same objects.

Comment: I will try the first one. But for being deleted twice, it is not the case as I check the server and the object is still there.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you have read and write permissions for your class
2. the deleting could be failing because the ACL for the rows created in your class only have the read permission. To allow both read and write permissions, in your AppDelegate under method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" you will see lines

let defaultACL = PFACL();

// If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
defaultACL.getPublicReadAccess = true

add the line --- defaultACL.getPublicWriteAccess = true

this will help you create all rows with write permissions so that in future you can delete an object from the client side.